# Add data attributes to a jquery array

Tags: jquery

I am trying to grab a data attribute from a list of divs and add it to a jquery array. Everytime I loop through I am getting empty data. The select element works as I tested this on an array I created. It's a noob question, sorry but I am going around in circles.

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="poop" data-colour="blue"> blue </div>
<div class="poop" data-colour="green"> green </div>
<div class="poop" data-colour="yellow"> yellow </div>
<div class="new-select"></div>
<script>
var data2 = [];
$('.poop').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  arr.push([ $this.data('colour') ]);
});
var s = $('<select />');
for(var val in data2) {
    $('<option />', {value: val, text: data[val]}).appendTo(s);
}

s.appendTo('.new-select');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. `for...in...` is for objects and not arrays, 2. You're pushing an array with one element instead of only the color in a undefined variable

Comment: The `data2` is never been pushed to. The `arr.push()` might thrown an error.

Comment: I just worked out that the data2 was not tagged in the array push. Thanks Praveen.

Answer (score 0):

There's several issues in your logic, primarily to do with the variables you define, and how you are/are not using them. For example you never define `arr` as an array to push to, `data2` is always empty as you never do anything with it, and `data` is also undefined so `data[val]` will cause an error. Finally, the `for` loop variant you use will have issues when used with an array.

To tidy the logic up you could use `map()` to build an array of the `option` elements as strings, then apply those to the `select` you create using `html()`, like this;

```js
var html = $('.poop').map(function() {
  var col = $(this).data('colour');
  return `<option value="${col}">${col}</option>`;
}).get().join('');

var $s = $('<select />').html(html);
$s.appendTo('.new-select');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="poop" data-colour="blue">blue</div>
<div class="poop" data-colour="green">green</div>
<div class="poop" data-colour="yellow">yellow</div>
<div class="new-select"></div>
```

This logic avoids having to use two loops. If you'd prefer to have a multiple loops to create the colour array separately, then you can still use `map()`, like this:

```js
var colours = $('.poop').map(function() {
  return $(this).data('colour');
}).get();

var $s = $('<select />');
colours.forEach(function(colour) {
  $s.append(`<option value="${colour}">${colour}</option>`);
});
$s.appendTo('.new-select');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="poop" data-colour="blue">blue</div>
<div class="poop" data-colour="green">green</div>
<div class="poop" data-colour="yellow">yellow</div>
<div class="new-select"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Rory, that worked, I can see you are not using the arrays too, which is great and what I was trying to do initially. Thanks for your help on such a simple thing. Now to try to remove the duplicates.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score -1):

1. There is no need to `var $this = $(this)` line because in this case we don't need to keep previous `this` variable (we would not have new scope and so new `this`).
2. The `arr` variable never defined so I only used `data2`.
3. To get an array of 3 elements (`['blue, 'green', 'yellow']`), you should pass just each value to `push` method. But by `push([ $this.data('colour') ])` you would get an array of 3 arrays (`[ ['blue'], ['green'], ['yellow'] ]`).
4. Although I didn't want change all part of your code but according to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in) and friends' comments, you should use `for...in` just for Objects not Arrays. You can use `for...of` instead.

Hope to help.

```js
var data2 = [];
$('.poop').each(function(){
  data2.push($(this).data('colour'));
});

console.log(data2) // ["blue", "green", "yellow"]

var s = $('<select />');
for(var val of data2) {
    $('<option />', {value: val, text: data2[val]}).appendTo(s);
}

s.appendTo('.new-select');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="poop" data-colour="blue"> blue </div>
<div class="poop" data-colour="green"> green </div>
<div class="poop" data-colour="yellow"> yellow </div>
<div class="new-select"></div>
```

Comment: Cool another answer using the array, this helps me to learn a few approaches. Thank you for the response Alizadeh.

Comment: Shouldn't be using `for in` on arrays

Comment: glad to help @insomniac22

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, it's updated. @charlietfl